# Facing a problem with Odoo 14 custom Module

Tags: odoo-14

It's an error that happen when I want to install the module, and after hours of search on the internet, hours of just reading Odoo's code... I was able to install and run the module but still getting this error

I get the following error when updating the Module I cant figure out how to add the config_ok, I tried the following but still didn't work

I added


but no luck

```html
Field config_ok used in attrs.invisible ({'invisible': ['|', ('config_ok','=',True), ('product_variant_count', '<=', 1)]}) must be present in view but is missing.

View name: product.template.common.form
Error context:
 view: ir.ui.view(2092,)
 xmlid: product_template_form_view_inherit
 view.model: product.template
 view.parent: ir.ui.view(878,)
 file: /home/odoo/src/user/product_configurator/views/product_view.xml
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<data>

    <record id="product_template_form_view_procurement_button" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template_procurement.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.product_template_form_view_procurement_button"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//header/button[@name='action_update_quantity_on_hand']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': ['|', ('product_variant_count', '&lt;', 1), ('type', '!=', 'product')]}</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="product_template_form_view_inherite" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.common.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="priority">16</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//header/button[@name='%(product.product_attribute_value_action)d']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': ['|', ('config_ok','=',True), ('product_variant_count', '&lt;=', 1)]}</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <div name="button_box" position="inside">
                <button class="oe_stat_button" name="toggle_config"
                    type="object" icon="fa-wrench" groups="product_configurator.group_product_configurator_manager">
                    <field name="config_ok"  options='{"active": "Configurable", "inactive": "Standard"}' widget="boolean_button"/>
                </button>
            </div>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="product_template_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.configurator.product.template.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="priority">16</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr='//header' position="inside">
                <button class="oe_stat_button" name="get_product_attribute_values_action"
                    attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('attribute_line_ids', '=', []), ('config_ok', '=', False)]}"
                    groups="product_configurator.group_product_configurator_manager"
                    type="object"
                    string="Variant Prices">
                </button>
                <button name="configure_product"
                    class="oe_highlight"
                    type="object"
                    string="Configure Product"
                    groups="product_configurator.group_product_configurator"
                    attrs="{'invisible': [('config_ok', '=', False)]}"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//label[@for='purchase_ok' or @for='sale_ok']" position="after">
                <div class="oe_left" name="options" groups="base.group_user">
                    <field name="id" invisible="True"/>
                </div>
            </xpath>

            <!-- Product attributes -->
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='attribute_line_ids']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="context">{
                    'show_attribute': False,
                    'attribute_line_ids': attribute_line_ids,
                }</attribute>
            </xpath>

            <!-- TODO: Implement a method to hide this field for non-configurable product templates -->
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='attribute_line_ids']/tree/field[@name='value_ids']" position="after">
                <field name="default_val"
                    domain="[('id', 'in', value_ids)]"
                    context="{'show_attribute': False}"
                    options="{'no_create': True, 'no_create_edit': True}"
                    invisible="not context.get('default_config_ok', False)"/>
                <field name="required" invisible="not context.get('default_config_ok', False)"/>
                <field name="multi" invisible="not context.get('default_config_ok', False)" attrs="{'readonly': [('custom','=',True)]}" force_save="1"/>
                <field name="custom" invisible="not context.get('default_config_ok', False)" attrs="{'readonly': [('multi','=',True)]}" force_save="1"/>
            </xpath>

            <xpath expr="//field[@name='attribute_line_ids']/tree/field[@name='value_ids']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'required': [('custom','!=',True)]}</attribute>
            </xpath>

            <xpath expr="//field[@name='attribute_line_ids']/tree/field[@name='attribute_id']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="context">{'flag_config_ok': not parent and context.get('default_config_ok', False) or parent.config_ok}</attribute>
            </xpath>

            <xpath expr="//field[@name='attribute_line_ids']/tree/field[@name='attribute_id']" position="before">
                <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
            </xpath>

            <!-- TODO: Apply domains so only values from template are available -->
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='variants']" position="after">
                <page string="Configurator" name="configurator" attrs="{'invisible': [('config_ok','=',False)]}" groups="product_configurator.group_product_configurator">
                <separator colspan="4" string="Configuration Restrictions" name="configurator_restrictions"/>
                <field name="config_line_ids"
                       attrs="{'readonly': [('attribute_line_ids','=',[])]}"
                       context="{'show_attribute': False}">
                    <tree string="Attribute Value Dependencies" editable="bottom">
                        <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
                        <field name="attribute_line_id"
                               domain="[('product_tmpl_id','=',parent.id)]"
                               options="{'no_create': True, 'no_create_edit': True}"/>
                        <!-- # TODO: Find a more elegant way to restrict the value_ids -->
                        <field name="attr_line_val_ids"
                               widget="many2many_tags"
                               invisible="True"/>
                        <field name="value_ids"
                               widget="many2many_tags"
                               attrs="{'readonly': [('attribute_line_id','=',False)]}"
                               domain="[('id','in',attr_line_val_ids)]"
                               options="{'no_create': True, 'no_create_edit': True}"
                               context="{'show_attribute': False}"/>
                        <field name="domain_id" context="{'product_tmpl_id': product_tmpl_id or active_id or parent.id, 'product_attribute_ids': template_attribute_ids}"/>
                        <field name="product_tmpl_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="template_attribute_ids" invisible="1"/>

                    </tree>
                </field>
                <separator colspan="4" string="Configuration Steps" name="configurator_steps"/>
                <field name="config_step_line_ids"
                       attrs="{'readonly': [('attribute_line_ids','=',[])]}">
                    <tree string="Configuration Steps" editable="bottom">
                        <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
                        <field name="config_step_id"/>
                        <field name="attribute_line_ids"
                               domain="[('product_tmpl_id', '=', parent.id)]"
                               options="{'no_create': True, 'no_create_edit': True}"
                               widget="many2many_tags"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
                <separator colspan="4" string="Configuration Images" name="configurator_images"/>
                <field name="config_image_ids">
                    <tree editable="bottom" string="Configuration Images">
                        <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="value_ids" widget="many2many_tags" context="{'_cfg_product_tmpl_id': parent.id}"/>
                        <field name="image_1920" widget="image" height="30px"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
                <field name="attribute_line_val_ids" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="attribute_value_line_ids" invisible="1">
                    <tree string="Attribute value lines" editable="bottom" context="{'default_product_tmpl_id': self.id}">
                        <field name="product_tmpl_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="attribute_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
                        <field name="value_id"
                               domain="[('id', 'in', parent.attribute_line_val_ids)]"/>
                        <field name="value_ids"
                               domain="[
                                ('id', 'in', parent.attribute_line_val_ids),
                                ('attribute_id', '!=', attribute_id)
                               ]" widget="many2many_tags"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
                <separator string="Variant Name" colspan="4" groups="product_configurator.group_product_configurator_manager"/>
                    <field name="mako_tmpl_name" groups="product_configurator.group_product_configurator_manager"/>
                </page>
            </xpath>

            <xpath expr="//field[@name='default_code']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('config_ok','=',True)]}</attribute>
            </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="product_template_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.configurator.product.template.search.view</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_search_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//filter[@name='filter_to_sell']" position="after">
                <separator/>
                <filter string="Standard Products" name="filter_standard_products" domain="[('config_ok','=',False)]"/>
                <filter string="Configurable Products" name="filter_config_ok" domain="[('config_ok','=',True)]"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="template_view_tree_configurable" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.product.tree</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_tree_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='default_code']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">context.get('default_config_ok', 0)</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="product_template_kanban_view_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Product.template.product.kanban</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_kanban_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//kanban" position="inside">
                <field name="config_ok"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//div/div[2]" position="before">
                <div class="pull-right" groups="product_configurator.group_product_configurator" attrs="{'invisible': [('config_ok', '=', False)]}">
                    <a name="configure_product" type="object">
                        <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-lg"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="product_form_view_custom_vals_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.configurator.form.view.custom.vals</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr='//header' position="inside">
                <button string="Variant Prices" type="object"
                    name="get_product_attribute_values_action"
                    attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('product_template_attribute_value_ids', '=', False), ('config_ok', '=', False)]}"
                    groups="product_configurator.group_product_configurator_manager"/>
                <button name="reconfigure_product" groups="product_configurator.group_product_configurator"
                        class="oe_highlight"
                        type="object"
                        string="Reconfigure Product"
                        attrs="{'invisible': [('config_ok','=',False)]}"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//button[@name='toggle_config']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//div[@name='options']" position="inside">
                <field name="config_preset_ok" attrs="{'invisible': [('config_ok', '=', False)]}"/>
                <label for="config_preset_ok" attrs="{'invisible': [('config_ok', '=', False)]}"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="product_variant_easy_edit_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.product.view.form.easy</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_variant_easy_edit_view"/>
        <field name="mode">primary</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='active']" position="after">
                <field name="config_ok" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="config_preset_ok" attrs="{'invisible': [('config_ok', '=', False)]}"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='weight']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly': [('config_ok', '=', True)]}</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="product_kanban_view_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Product Kanban</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_kanban_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//kanban" position="inside">
                <field name="config_ok"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//div/div[2]/strong[hasclass('o_kanban_record_title')]" position="after">
                <div class="pull-right" groups="product_configurator.group_product_configurator" attrs="{'invisible': [('config_ok', '=', False)]}">
                    <a name="reconfigure_product" type="object" class="fa fa-repeat fa-lg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
</odoo>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons for this error:

If you haven't tried basic solution, **first solution**:

1. Activate developer mode
2. Open users and set filter to display
3. Inactive Set OdooBot as an internal user

**Second solution**: explicitly add **xpath** for missing field abov attribue xpath.

```
<xpath expr="//header/button[@name='action_update_quantity_on_hand']" position="before">
    <field name="config_ok" />
</xpath>
```

Let me know, if any of above don't work.

Comment: Hi Sayyam, Thank you adding <field name="config_ok" /> did solve the problem, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi Sayyam, Sorry to keep bothering you, I have another error in the same view, I tried following the same by adding the missing Field but no luck, what is it that am doing wrong error message:Field parent used in context.flag_config_ok ({'flag_config_ok': not parent and context.get('default_config_ok', False) or parent.config_ok}) must be present in view but is missing.